# How to optimize this PL/SQL block?

Tags: plsql

I need to update the column named `text` in the table named `table_to_update`. The field `text` is a concatentation of 3 strings from another table called `other_table`. The script works as expected, but the problem is that it takes a long time to execute (>20hours) since there are about 20millions data sets in the table `table_to_update` which needs to be updated.

Are there any ideas how I can improve the perfromance of this script?

```
DECLARE
 v_field1 VARCHAR(20);
 v_field2 VARCHAR(20);
 v_field3 VARCHAR(20);
 v_text VARCHAR(100);


BEGIN
 FOR rec IN (select t_pk from table_to_update where state = 'STATE_1' and text is null order by t_pk desc) -- 20 millions data sets
LOOP

 v_text := null;

  FOR other_record IN (select distinct field1, field1, field3 from other_table where t_fk = rec.t_pk)
  LOOP
    v_field1 := other_record.field1;
    v_field2 := other_record.field2;
    v_field3 := other_record.field3;
    v_text := v_text || v_field2 || ';' || v_field1 || ': '|| v_field3 || ' ';        
  END LOOP;   

update table_to_update set text = v_text where t_pk = rec.t_pk;

END LOOP;

COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Does this have to be PL/SQL? Why not just use raw SQL with a subquery to handle the string manipulation?

Comment: @mmmmmpie: The inner loop is aggregating the concatenated strings, so it's not quite as straightforward as it seems.

Comment: Right I was typing a comment about the `MERGE` statement as you answered it. :)

Comment: The issue is definitely that he is distinctly updating 20 million records. Handle all of them through 1 update statement and he will see significant performance increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking the best way to optimize a PL/SQL block is to minimize the number of context switches (i.e. how often you switch from procedural code to SQL and back). In this case, you can reduce this block to a single statement (assuming you're using 11g or later):

```
MERGE INTO table_to_update t2u
USING      (SELECT   t_fk,
                     LISTAGG (field2 || ';' || field1 || ': ' || field3, ' ')
                        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field2)
                        AS agg_field
            FROM     other_table
            GROUP BY t_fk) ot
ON         (ot.t_fk = t2u.t_pk)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET
      t2u.text = ot.agg_field
      WHERE      t2u.state = 'STATE_1' AND t2u.text IS NULL
```

- `LISTAGG` is a aggregate function that concatenates values obtained
  from different rows. It was introduced in 11g.
- You could do this as an `UPDATE` as well, but I prefer `MERGE`.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast answer. I will try this out and will answer you soon.